# Video.js: Unable to hide controls (through options)

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to hide the playercontrols but nothing I do seems to work, here's my code (all the other options work, the video loops and autoplays):

```
videojs('hero_video', {
    'controls': false,
    'autoplay': true,
    'preload': 'auto',
    'loop': true
});
```

The videotag looks like this:

```
    <video poster="images/temp/slider.jpg" id="hero_video">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video/cows.mp4" />
        <source type="video/webm" src="video/cows.webm" />
        <source type="video/ogg" src="video/cows.ogv" />
    </video>
```

I'm aware this could be done using css but I'd like to not have a bunch of extra markup on my page.

Comment: It is working properly for me, check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/6nJ4z/10/
Controls are only visible if you have `controls: true`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, turns out the markup for the controls get rendered regardless of the 'controls' setting, it just toggles wether it is visible or not.